# Can use WSO2 4.1 APIM and WSO2 Analytics together

Tags: wso2, analytics, open-source, wso2-api-manager

We are using WSO2 APIM 4.1 version and we are looking to configure APIM Analytics, can we use old WSO2 APIM Analytics together with 4.1 version without Choreo which is not available as free.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't use the old APIM Analytics with the latest APIM version, but instead of Choreo you can use ELK Stack to push your analytics data. Have a look at [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/). At the same time, you can also write your own [event publisher](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-analytics-events-to-external-systems/) to publish Analytics to any external system.

Comment: HI @ycr is it show usage of API as per user, API subcription by user and other thing like old do

Comment: @VikasPatil I'm not sure about the subscription data. But I assume it would show all the Matrics that were shown in the previous version. Here is what you will see https://wso2.com/choreo/docs/insights/view-api-insights/. Most of the data you mentioned will be Pushed to ELK, you may have to create your own Dashbords to show the data you need.

Comment: thanks entire done things done work well